# How to get only the subfolders of my cwd in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I need to get the subfolders of my current working directory.

I've tried with the `os` module and found the `tree`-command. I just need to get the subfolders not the sub-sub-sub-folders or whatever is in the subfolders.

Here is what I currently got:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
dirctorys  = os.tree(cwd)
```

I created a `for` loop to print my tree, but this prints all the subfolders, **including** it's content. But I just need the subfolders, nothing else!

For example these are my directorys:

```
root/me/cwd
        |-__init__.py
        |-mygeo.py
        |-subfolder1
        |    |-file1.py
        |    |-file2.py
        |-subfolder2
        |    |-file3.py
        |    |-subsubfolder
        |    |    |-foo.py
        |    |    |-foo2.py
```

I want python to return a tuple or a list having this in it:

```
['__init__.py', 'mygeo.py', 'subfolder1', 'subfolder2']
```

I've analyzed the output of `os.tree(cwd)` when I printed it and found out that it's made out of lists. The first list seems to be exactly what I need, but I don't know how to get it.

How can I get such a list?

Comment: Does `os` module has attribute `tree()`?

Comment: I does and it gives me everything in anything in the directorys

Comment: @h_e_u_r_e_k_a: It does not. There is an [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), but the output you're showing is more like what the *NIX [`tree` utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) prints.

Comment: Sorry, it is walk, I derped out! I didn't see m code while writing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir()`:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
contents = os.listdir(cwd)
```

If you want to split the files from the directories:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
_, files, directories = next(os.walk(cwd))
```

Comment: Since this is Python 3, if it's actually 3.5 or higher, I should point out that [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) would make it easy to get the directories in a given path even more quickly and easily: `directories = [entry.name for entry in os.scandir() if entry.is_dir()]`.

Comment: Just a note that python 3.6.3 the order of "files" and "directories" is swapped.